How to efficiently use generics in Python to type-hint a function with two arguments of the same type (either int or str)?
I have a function that takes two arguments of the same type, which could be either int or str. My initial implementation without generics looks like this:
python
def combine1(a: int | str, b: int | str) -> int | str:
    match a:
        case int():
            match b:
                case int():
                    return a + b
                case str():
                    return "error"
        case str():
            match b:
                case int():
                    return "error"
                case str():
                    return a + b

This implementation is inefficient because it checks the type of b even though we know it must have the same type as a. It also allows for the possibility of a and b having different types, which isn't the intended behavior.
To improve this, I want to use generics to make mypy understand that a and b have the same type. Here's my attempt:
python
def combine2[T: int | str](a: T, b: T) -> T:
    match a:
        case int():
            return a + b
        case str():
            return a + b

However, mypy reports the following errors:

text error: Incompatible return value type (got "int", expected "T")
[return-value] error: Unsupported operand types for + ("int" and "T")
[operator] error: Incompatible return value type (got "str", expected
"T")  [return-value] error: Unsupported operand types for + ("T" and
"T")  [operator]

How can I modify this function to correctly use generics and satisfy mypy's type checking, while ensuring that the function only accepts two arguments of the same type (either both int or both str) and avoiding the inefficiency of the first implementation?
This question is not the same as this one: How to use type hint to make sure two variables always have the same type?
because I try to propose to solve this problem by using generic. What this question doesn t.
Furthermore this question doesn't use pattern matching inside the function. My point is avoiding to check two time the type of variables because I already know they have the same type. I would like to just check the type T.
A good solutation that doesn't work would be to use pattern matching on the type T instead of a variable
I tried this too:
def combine3[T : int | str](a: T, b: T) -> T:
    match a,b:
        case int(),int():
            return a +b
        case str(), str():
            return a+b


error: Missing return statement  [return] error: Incompatible return
value type (got "int", expected "T")  [return-value] error:
Incompatible return value type (got "str", expected "T")
[return-value]

mypy isn't able to understand that the 2 case I proposed are the only possible one. To remove the first error I have to add a default case
def combine4[T : int | str](a: T, b: T) -> T:
    match a,b:
        case int(),int():
            return a +b
        case str(), str():
            return a+b
        case _ :
            return a


error: Incompatible return value type (got "int", expected "T")  [return-value]
error: Incompatible return value type (got "str", expected "T")  [return-value]


But I really cannot undersand why it say the function returns int or str instead of T.

Possible duplicate: How to use type hint to make sure two variables always have the same type?. You want T: (int, str) rather than T: int | str.

The only answer there mentions two solutions, the second of which is what you are looking for, just in old syntax.

@InSync This is not exactly what I want. my example is a simplified example. In this simplied example, I do the same things for int and for str. But for real I am not doing the same thing. Therefore I really need to make 2 case for reach type. And the propososed answer don t do that. (not with match, not with isisntance)

the type overload brings nothing, because there is still only one function definition. And the version without warning is still the inefficiant one.  The efficiant version get warning from mypy

If this example does not reflect your real use case, then please [edit] the question to clarify. Also, T: (str, int) should help with the warnings.

@InSync I am still on this question. I can not test what I send me right now. But I will test it. Hopefully before the end of the day

@InSync. I think I just made a silly mistake. I Wrote  T: str | int instead of (int, str). Because I though the second syntax as telling T could be only a tuple of int and str

But I don t understand why you us@InSync e the 2 asserts in the 3rd case. It works fine without the third case and the assert for me

Those assert_never() calls are used to show that all cases have been considered, and the case _: branch is never reached.

(This pattern is recommended because it helps preventing unhandled cases.)

ok but if there are unhandled case, mypy issues a warning. If there are no warning from mypy there are no unhandle case?

That's correct.

This question is similar to: How can I ensure that arguments have same type without listing the types explicitly?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This code works
def combine2[T: (int, str)](a: T, b: T) -> T:
    match a:
        case int():
            return a + b
        case str():
            return a + b

combine2(1,1)
#combine2("h",1) mypy returns an error but this is normal. I don t want the arguments to have a differnet type
combine2("s","j")
#combine2(3,"j") mypy returns an error but this is normal. I don t want the arguments to have a differnet type


If you set bounds on the TypeVar, this issue goes away. I think essentially the new generic syntax doesn't allow you to specify bounds in this way:
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", int, str)

def combine(a: T, b: T) -> T:
    match a:
        case int():
            return a + b
        case str():
            return a + b

Hope this is useful!
